# Typeorm is always mapping "timestamp without timezone" to Date object

Tags: timezone, nestjs, typeorm

Here is a simple entity in typeorm, I have the createdAt and updatedAt columns that are of type "timestamp without time zone" ( as postgres does not support "datetime" type ) and I set the type of these as "string".

```
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";
import { City } from "./city.entity";

@Entity("country")
export class Country {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 255 })
    name: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 255 })
    nationality: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp without time zone", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
    createdAt: string;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp without time zone", onUpdate: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nullable: true })
    updatedAt: string;

    // relations
    @OneToMany(() => City, (city) => city.country, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    cities: City[];
}
```

and here is the initialization of TypeOrmModule in app.module.ts
I get the database config and destructure it here, then set the timezone to "UTC" and dateStrings to parse the columns in entites that have the type "timestamp without time zone" to strings instead of Date objects.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
          ...config.get<TypeOrmModuleOptions>("db"),
          dateStrings: ["timestamp without time zone"],
          timezone: "UTC",
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

Im using postgres 13, and the database timezone is UTC (+00:00).

What is happening is the createdAt column in the database is correct as it should be in UTC, but when i try to get the records from database, the column is being parsed to Date object instead of returning a string

here is an example:

[image: database country record]

as you can see, the createdAt column has a value of 9:58 in UTC
I am currently in GMT+2, and here is how the record is returned in postman

`{

```
    "id": "e979610f-0995-4192-a821-cb0fd222253f",
    "name": "France",
    "nationality": "French",
    "createdAt": "2023-07-12T07:58:22.074Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-12T07:58:22.074Z"
```

},`

it is parsing the createdAt from UTC to GMT+2 (with timrzone "T")

I need the column to stay in UTC, so the I can parse it correctly to each user's timezone on the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Might be late to the party, but the most straightforward solution would be to set `type: 'timestamp with time zone'` (postgres [supports that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)) in order to explicitly define that you are using UTC, so typeorm would return adequate values.